# How can I display umlauts in C++ console app?

Tags: c++

I have this problem that Umlauts don't get displayed properly, and I've already tried to localise it, but somehow my console app can't read it and it still produces gibberish? How can I localise umlauts/the sharp S?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    locale loc;
    locale::global(locale("German"));

    cout << "ÄÖÜ äöü ß\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: Are you sure those are umlauts? Is this file saved in the same encoding your terminal uses? The locale doesn't matter. The *character set* does.

Comment: Does your output device even support those characters - would be the obvious first question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl My device supports umlauts, but this problem hasn't appeared until recently for some reason...

Comment: We'll need to go into more detail than "my device supports umlauts". You need to be aware of the encoding of your source file, the encodings supported by your compiler (less of a concern in general) and the encoding mode of the terminal on which you're viewing the data. What are they? And what happens if they're all, say, UTF-8?

Comment: It depends on your OS. With Linux it works  out of the box https://wandbox.org/permlink/9n4Of7iNEls4H9tL

Comment: You have to configure your console to use `UTF-8` (or whatever encoding your `C++` application is outputting). Basically the console must be given whatever encoding it is configured to receive from your application.

Comment: @ThomasSablik That is, again, an oversimplification. The Wandbox stack happens to (read: has been made to) use a consistent encoding from the web input, through to the compiler, to the program output and back to the web output. That's not necessarily inherent to any of those steps.

Comment: _"this problem hasn't appeared until recently for some reason"_ I would focus on trying to remember what you've changed, out of any/all the above listed components.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica it works the same on my computer in a Linux terminal but I can't show it here.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I haven't changed anything significant though? I've always been using this method of localising umlauts and it has worked perfectly, but it has stopped working for some reason. I now get a C26444 warning message (I use Visual Studio 2019) and the code is ignored...

Comment: You may want to think about treating letters with umlauts as single glyphs (or characters), rather than a character then superimposing umlauts.

Comment: @ThomasSablik It works there for the same reason

Comment: @Dead Clearly _something_ changed... As for "this method" I'm not sure what you mean by that. Which method? The locale instantiation? That does next to nothing

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't see where the OP is doing that atm?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica The question is tagged with C++ only. There are no information about the system. I wanted to show that it isn't a pure C++ problem and it can't be solved without these information. There are systems where it works and systems where it doesn't. If OP doesn't provide more information it's difficult to help. Until now OP didn't provide the OS.

Comment: Again @ThomasSablik it's not about the system _per se_ but about how the individual components being used are configured.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica in our company the configuration of a system and its components is part of a system. If we say that two systems are different it doesn't necessarily mean that OS is different. It can mean that a small setting is different. Two different terminal emulators make two different systems because the system could behave differently. OP doesn't describe the system. We only know it's probably a Microsoft product. I presented a __configuration__ that works out of the box.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am using Windows as my OS.

Comment: Here was a discussion how many components and configurations of your system can change the behavior and the only information you give is it's Windows. Not even the version. An update or patch could change the behavior. Nothing about which terminal emulator you use. For me it sounds like you're not interested in help.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am, please dont think that! I am just a bit confused right now as I am still a rookie at programming. The most info I can give right now is that I use Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019, Update 16.3.9. Pardon my obtuseness.